# Pipe Ipython magic output to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I want to run a bash script in my ipython Notebook and save the output as a string in a python variable for further manipulation. Basically I want to pipe the output of the bash magic to a variable,
For example the output of something like this:

```
%%bash
some_command [options] foo bar
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

What about using this:

```
myvar = !some_command --option1 --option2 foo bar
```

instead of the `%%bash` magic? Using the `!` symbol runs the following command as a shell command, and the results are all stored in `myvar`. For running multiple commands and collecting the output of all of them, just put together a quick shell script.

Comment: Is it possible to differentiate between stdout and stderr?

Comment: @Vinayak With the `%%capture` cell magics you can distinguish stdout and stderr easily.  See [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture) and [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.utils.capture.html). Looks akin to oLas's answer below but offers another route.

Answer (score 30):

For completeness, if you would still like to use the `%%bash` cell magic, you can pass the `--out` and `--err` flags to redirect the outputs from the stdout and stderr to a variable of your choice.

From the [doucumentation](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Cell%20Magics.ipynb):

```
%%bash --out output --err error
echo "hi, stdout"
echo "hello, stderr" >&2
```

will store the outputs in the variables `output` and `error` so that:

```
print(error)
print(output)
```

will print to the python console:

```
hello, stderr
hi, stdout
```

Answer (score 13):

Notice the difference in the variable type between @MattDMo (`SList`) and @oLas (`str`) answers:

```
In [1]: output = !whoami

In [2]: type(output)
Out[2]: IPython.utils.text.SList

In [3]: %%bash --out output
   ...: whoami

In [4]: type(output)
Out[4]: str
```