# Programmatically get current IPython notebook cell output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have an imported function that runs in an IPython notebook (input cell X) which produces an output (in output cell X). After the function runs, I have some more code (also in input cell X); is there any way for that code to retrieve the current output (in output cell X)?

There may be other ways to do what I am trying to achieve; but I am curious if the above is possible.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

IPython's [output caching system](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system) defines several global variables:

- [`_`] (a single underscore): stores previous output, like Python’s default interpreter.
- [`__`] (two underscores): next previous.
- [`___`] (three underscores): next-next previous.

Additionally, after each output `x` is created, there is a variable `_<x>` created with the output as its value. For example:

```
In [12]: lst = [i for i in range(11)]

In [13]: lst
Out[13]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

In [14]: _13
Out[14]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Also, if you're interested, `_i<x>` contains the contents of the input cell `x`:

```
In [15]: _i12
Out[15]: 'lst = [i for i in range(11)]'
```

Comment: In addition, if this is from a 'magic' command rather than a Python function [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704063/pipe-ipython-magic-output-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 14):

You can get the output of the cell X by using `_` or `Out[X]`. Such as:

```
In [1]: 2 + 35
Out[1]: 37
In [2]: _ + 3
Out[2]: 40 
In [3]: lst = [i for i in range(5)]
        lst
Out[3]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
In [4]: Out[1] #Using the output of Cell 1
Out[4]: 37
In [5]: Out[3][1] #Using the output of Cell 3
Out[5]: 1
```

Here, If you want to get the output of the previous cell, then you can use `_`. You can use two (`__`) or three underscores(`___`) as well to refer to output of the next previous and next-next previous cells respectively.

However, if you have many cells in the notebook and you want to refer some particular cell, then `Out[X]` will be helpful.

Comment: If used in Jupyter (yes, I know the question has Ipython as a headline) this doesn't work quite as I at least expected. Out[3] for example does not give the output of cell 3, but the third output of any kind. Eg if you run cell 1 three times, Out[3] will be the third value.

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers don't work for when a cell calls a function that generates its own `stdout`.

I found a different solution that catches all of the output of the previous cell, no matter how it was produced.

```
# cell 1:
%%capture output
print("blah")
func_that_prints("Bha")
# -----------------
# cell 2:
prev_cell_output = str(output)
# do something with prev_cell_output
```

Note that `%%capture` line must the very first line of a cell for it to work. `output` can be renamed to any other variable name. There will be no output for the first cell displayed (as it'll be captured).

`output` becomes available only in the following cell. It is a `utils.io.CapturedIO` object, so you can stringify it, or even call `.show()` on it, which will display its contents.

For more information, e.g. capturing just `stdout`, or just `stderr` use the [reference](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture).