# Transforme jupyter notebook to script and launch it repeatedly with different values for a set of variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I do machine learning using jupyter notebooks.

Usually I start on a new project by writing simple code for example to split train and test set I will write:

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Later I will start finding variable that I often want to change so I will write:

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)
```

and I will define my variable like `test_size=0.2` in a cell at the begining of the notebook where I define a list of variables.

But let's say that know i want to experiment and launch the notebook with different values of `tets_size`. I would like to do something like this:

```
 for i in [0.1*j for j in range(1,5)]:
     test_size = i
     execute_everything_in_notebook(test_size)
```

So one way to do that would be to download the notebook as python file, add some code to read argument from outside the file with argparse (or by reading a dictionary with the values) and then launch it from another file. The problem is that I have to write a lot of boring code like `parser.add_argument('--test_size', type=int)` which take time, I feel like it could be done faster as all my variables are defined clearly in a single cell of the notebooks. So is there a fast way (even if it's not very clean or pythonic) to launch my notebooks as a script changing some variables at each call, knowing that the variable I want to change are all cleanly defined in an isolated cell.

Comment: I find a way to create a dictionnary with all the variables dfined in the cells here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824287/print-all-variables-defined-in-one-jupyter-cell. But know I would need to pass this dictionnary as argument so that each `key:value` become a variable. I can save the dictionnary and read it from the script, but then I would still have to change every `variable=variable_value` by `variable=load_dict['variable]` which is long.

Answer (score 0):

Many possible way to do it.
like pipeline most common and popular to used with dataset.

but you want to change hyper-parameter of train test split function and mostly pipeline is used after the train-test split function. So there is way to it.

**Suggestion :**

1. In place of change the 'test_size' hyper parameter of train_test_split function use use grid-search cross validation. (RandomizedSearchCV is also better option).
2. Change 'random_state' hyper-parameter is gives good results some times.

Code:

```
    from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
    from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    def classify(model, X, y):
        best_score = []
        for i in np.arange(0.1,0.5,0.1):
            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = i, random_state = 21167)
            model.fit(X_train, y_train)
            best_model = model.best_estimator_
            best_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
            y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)
            score = best_model.score(y_test, y_pred)
            best_score.append(score)
        return best_score
```

After execute the above code then execute the below code:

```
    X = dataset.drop(column = ['target_column_name'], axis = 1)
    y = dataset['target_column_name']

    pipe = Pipeline([('standardscaling',StandardScaler()),
                     ('pca', PCA(n_components = 20)),
                     ('classifier', LogisticRegression())]) # this the pipeline where you can add the operation performed by you in same sequence like standardscaler then, pca then, model like logisticregression 
    
    grid_param = [
                    {"classifier": [LogisticRegression()],
                     "classifier__penalty": ['l2'],
                     "classifier__C": np.logspace(0, 4, 10),
                     "classifier__solver":['newton-cg','saga','sag','liblinear'] ##This solvers don't allow L1 penalty
                     },
                    {"classifier": [DecisionTreeClassifier()],
                    "classifier__criterion" : ["gini","entropy"],
                    "classifier__max_depth" : [3,4,5],
                    "classifier__min_samples_leaf" : [3,5,7],
                    "classifier__random_state" : [0,5,10]
                    },
                    {"classifier": [RandomForestClassifier()],
                     "classifier__criterion" : ["gini","entropy"],
                     "classifier__n_estimators": [10, 100, 200],
                     "classifier__max_depth":[5,8,15,None],
                     "classifier__min_samples_leaf":[1,2,5,10],
                     "classifier__max_leaf_nodes": [2, 5,10],
                    },
                    {"classifier": [AdaBoostClassifier()],
                    "classifier__algorithm" : ['SAMME', 'SAMME.R'],
                    "classifier__random_state" : [0,5,10,15,20],
                    },
                    {"classifier": [BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5,
                                                            min_samples_leaf=5,
                                                            random_state=0))],
                    "classifier__n_estimators" : [20,30,40],
                    "classifier__bootstrap_features" : [True,False],
                    "classifier__oob_score" : [True,False],
                    "classifier__random_state" : [0,5,10],
                    },
                    {"classifier": [GradientBoostingClassifier()],
                    "classifier__min_samples_leaf" : [3,5],
                    "classifier__max_features" : ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
                    "classifier__random_state" : [10,15,20],
                    }
    ] # this is example of hyper parameter tunning
    
    gridsearch = GridSearchCV(pipe, grid_param, cv=4, verbose=0, n_jobs=-1) # Fit grid search
    best_score_list = classify(gridsearch, X, y)
    
    
    index = best_score_list.index(max(best_score)) # this help you to find out test_size value (use random_state value in palce of test_size)
    best_score_list[index]
```

- To learn more, ask questions.
- To move one step ahead, think different.
- Don't copy paste it. Understand it. Do it in your own way.
- Any query contact at 'kumartyagisumit@gmail.com'