# Execute the previous notebook cell in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to execute the previous cell from in jupyterlab ?

something like:

```
import IPython

IPython.exec_cell(-1)
```

I want to execute the previous cell (if it has been updated without having been re-executed). 
I have a cell that contains the test from the previous. If I modify the function, I want to only execute the cell that contains the test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically get current Ipython notebook cell output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952428/programmatically-get-current-ipython-notebook-cell-output)

Comment: You can run the previous (as in previous cell to run) through `%rerun` magic command. Documentation: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-rerun

Comment: @PeterWood no I want to reexecute the cell not get the output. If I change a function in the previous cell, I want to have the new function

Comment: @Swier the %rerun command execute the previous input (history) not the previous cell of a notebook.