# What is the purpose of "_104" in round function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

In round function what is the use of _100, _104, etc.
I know that round(10.121, 1) will round the value up to 1 decimal place.
But the purpose of _104 is not getting.

I've attached two screenshots for reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you have `print(_109)`?

Comment: @quamrana `NameError: name '_109' is not defined`

Comment: If we print(_109) it gives an output of 103.

Comment: I didn't use them.

Comment: @BramVanroy Restarted my system even same glitch.

Answer (score 1):

In IPython, `_109` means the output of the 109th cell execution. This implies that while you were running your IPython notebook (through VS Code), at cell execution 109, you received an output of 103. The reason why Bram above can't run `print(_109)` on his end is that he was either running it in a Python file/interpreter, or executing it in a fresh notebook where he hasn't run 109 cells yet, and thus the variable `_109` did not exist.

Check this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952661/2327379

Comment: Cool, didn't know that!