# How do I assign the output of a command to a variable in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to assign a value to a variable, that value which we get in terminal by writing any command?

I try with this code:

```
!number_of_lines=$(wc -l < cord_19.json)
!echo $number_of_lines
```

I get empty output. 
When I run

```
!wc -l < cord_19.json
```

I get correct response with number.

Do you have idea what is wrong or how can I set variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
number_of_lines = !wc -l < cord_19.json
!echo $number_of_lines
```

or:

```
number_of_lines = !wc -l < cord_19.json
print(number_of_lines)
```

See [Pipe Ipython magic output to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20704063/95) for related discussion.